# Regarding connecting MOV and SMPS in parallel for electrical meter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, voltmeter, mov

We are working on development of a 3 phase electrical metering circuitry. All the 3 phases are connected to metering IC using resistor divider circuitry for voltage measurement (between phase and neutral).

The rms voltages range from 200V to 260V  for all the three phases (between phase and neutral). However, the power supply for on-board components (3.3V and 5V) is drawn using an SMPS connected between phase 1 supply and neutral of the meter (no separate auxiliary supply is used).

All the three phases are equipped with 3 MOVs (275V rating) and each MOV is connected between one phase and neutral.

We installed these devices in 30 locations, out of which 5 stopped working after a few days. When analyzed, it is observed that the MOV connected along with the PCB track on phase 1 supply is blown in all the 5 devices. The MOVs of the other phases are just fine. We are unable to figure out what the mistake is.

Is there any chance that SMPS is resulting in the damage of the MOV? We are providing the schematic below for your reference. Any help or alternative design strategy is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What happens if the neutral is not connected?

Comment: We are currently measuring the potentials between a phase and neutral, and hence, MOV was connected between phase and neutral. Also, the SMPS we are using operates with 220V RMS (phase to neutral). Hence, the neutral is compulsory here for the circuit operation.

Comment: Ok, what happens if there is harmonics on the neutral or imbalance? Neutral has impedance, so it may not always be the 0V point we want it to be. Is there a common time to failure, or do the movs fail at random times?

Comment: We observed that the voltages (line to neutral) are in normal ranges (less than 260V). Of the five devices, two have blown during the load startup. The load current in normal operations would be 100A per phase and all the loads are 3 phase (such as induction motors). We are unsure of the other 3 devices. We are measuring these currents using CTs, and voltages in parallel to the load supply. Only the phase 1 MOV is damaged in all the devices. Only difference between phase 1 and other phases is SMPS connection. Other standard meters connected (such as by Schneider) at same place are not damaged.

Comment: Do we need to add any inductance between smps and MOV?